# Why UIButton can't stay selected state when disable?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIButton` which is set different images for normal and selected state.

I find that when I disable the button by setting `button.enable = NO`, even previous is selected state, the button will turn to normal state image, But I po the button selected value which is still YES.

How can I keep using selected image when button is disable? Is that the only way by changing normal state image when button change enable value?

Comment: `Disabled` is a kind of state of `UIButton`. You can set an image for `Disabled` state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the image for the case when button is Selected and Disabled as this is a different state that the solely other state. Set the image but for state like this:

```
UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateDisabled
```

[Control's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_State) state can be a combination of a few states from the list :)

As a nice lesson you can log changes of a control's state and see combinations of states it will gets in different cases.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift:

```
let state = UIControl.State.selected.union(UIControl.State.disabled)
```